# Get Percentage of True/False Associations in Active Record

Tags: sql, activerecord

I have the following models in my application -

```
Subscription
has_many :user_todos

UserTodo
belongs_to :subscription
```

`UserTodo` has a boolean field called `completed`

Is it possible for me to find a list of subscriptions where the number of user_todos completed are over 50%?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a custom sql query in conjunction with `find_by_sql`.

The custom sql query could then look as follows:

```sql
select * from subscription
where id in (
  select u1.subscription
  from usertodo u1
  group by u1.subscription
  having 
    (select count(*)
     from usertodo u2
     where u2.subscription = u1.subscription
       and u2.completed = true) >= 0.50 * count(*) 
)
```

The query assumes a the following schema. Of course, your schema will differ from this; but the structure is likely the same. I've tested the query in MySQL 5.6 (yet not with Active Records, as setting up the environment would have been a lot of work); hope it helps!

```sql
create table subscription (
  id int,
  name varchar(50)
 );

insert into subscription (id, name) values
  (1, "should be below 50 percent"), (2, "should be above 50 percent");

create table usertodo (
  subscription int,
  completed bool
  );

  insert into usertodo (subscription, completed) values
  (1, true),(1,false),(1,false),(2,true),(2,true),(2,false);
```